# Run Python, Extract XML data & map data to MySQL Table - Dataframe issue

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, xml, mysql-python

I started out with this snippet of code from another answer. However my issue is transforming the dataframe to a MySQL table displaying all of the rows in the database. See details below...

```
#reading mapping file and converting mapping to dictionary
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
map_path = 'D:\StackExchange\Mapping.xlsx'
if os.path.isfile(map_path):
    #map_df = pd.read_excel(map_path,worksheet='Mapping')
    map_df = pd.read_excel(map_path)
    mapping_dict = pd.Series(map_df['XML Columns'].values,index=map_df['SQL Columns']).to_dict()

#Reading XML file

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_path = 'D:\StackExchange\PostLinks.xml'
if os.path.isfile(xml_path):
        root = ET.parse(xml_path).getroot()

#Reading xml elements one by one and storing attributes in a dictionary.
#line 23 "if k in ['', '']:" <----- 'COLUMNname','COLUMNname','COLUMNname'
missing_col = []
xmldf_dict = {"df_dicts":[]}
for elem in root:
    df_dict = {}
    for k,v in mapping_dict.items():
        if k in ['Body']:
            continue
        try:
            df_dict[k] =  elem.attrib[v]
        except KeyError:
            missing_col.add(k)

    xmldf_dict["df_dicts"].append(df_dict)

#Merging missing columns dataframe with xml dataframe

missing_col_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=missing_col)
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xmldf_dict["df_dicts"])
final_df = pd.concat([xml_df,missing_col_df],axis=1)
#print(final_df)

my_conn=create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://sqluser:password@localhost/stackexchange_project")
df = pd.DataFrame(xmldf_dict["df_dicts"],index=0)
df.to_sql(con=my_conn,name='postlinks',if_exists='append',index=False)
```

The second to the last line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(xmldf_dict["df_dicts"],index=0)
```

I am trying to pass all of the xml data into the newly created Table in MySql. I get three results:

- MySQL error: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I've tried adjusting the code and sometimes it will also return Headers and one row, or just the headers. Appreciate your time!

Comment: that only means that it takes too long if you have the file on the mysql server try to run it directly

Comment: I was able to return the entire table into MySQL once, and I haven't been able to do it since. Anything helps, let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lost connection to MySQL server during query" means that the connection to the MySQL server is being lost during the execution of the to_sql() method

i would suggest writing to the server in chunks

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

xml_path = 'D:\StackExchange\PostLinks.xml'
if os.path.isfile(xml_path):
    root = ET.parse(xml_path).getroot()

# Define column mapping
mapping_dict = {
    "Id": "Id",
    "CreationDate": "CreationDate",
    "PostId": "PostId",
    "RelatedPostId": "RelatedPostId",
    "LinkTypeId": "LinkTypeId"
}

# Read xml elements one by one and store attributes in a dictionary
missing_col = set()
xmldf_dict = {"df_dicts":[]}
for elem in root:
    df_dict = {}
    for k, v in mapping_dict.items():
        if k == 'Body':
            continue
        try:
            df_dict[k] = elem.attrib[v]
        except KeyError:
            missing_col.add(k)

    xmldf_dict["df_dicts"].append(df_dict)

# Merge missing columns dataframe with xml dataframe
missing_col_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=missing_col)
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xmldf_dict["df_dicts"])
final_df = pd.concat([xml_df, missing_col_df], axis=1)

# Write data to MySQL database
my_conn = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://sqluser:password@localhost/stackexchange_project")

# Set chunksize to insert the data in smaller chunks
chunksize = 1000

for i in range(0, len(xmldf_dict["df_dicts"]), chunksize):
    chunk = xmldf_dict["df_dicts"][i:i+chunksize]
    df = pd.DataFrame(chunk)
    df.to_sql(con=my_conn, name='postlinks', if_exists='append', index=False)

print("Data written to MySQL database successfully!")
```

the only issue with this is if you run the code multiple times, it will continue to append new rows to the existing table, which may result in duplicate rows.

you can either drop the table and recreate it before running the code again, or use a different method such as if_exists='replace' to replace the entire table with the new data.

Comment: Worked! Now I just need to figure out of the limits of how large a snippet of xml data I can run in one go.